# Identifying repeat tracks on iTunes script

Tags: applescript, itunes

(Frustrated I can't figure out to do this with a 'where...' command.)
How can I add a song from my iTunes library to my playlist xMusic, ensuring it hasn't been added already?
At the moment I have an 'add some song whose genre is...' command and then a separate script to remove duplicates, but I'd rather make sure I'm not adding duplicates in the first place. 
Is there a way I can write something like 'set theSong to some song from playlist Music whose genre is Rock and whose name is not {go through titles of all other tracks so far added to xMusic}
Copy/Duplicate theSong to xMusic'.

Answer (score 1):

```
    use application "iTunes"


    set thePlaylistThatNeedsMoreSongs to user playlist "Music To Die To"
        --> user playlist id 22255 of source id 66 of application "iTunes"

    set theSongIWantToAdd to the first file track whose artist is "Raign"

    -- These are the playlists that contain theSongIWantToAdd
    playlists of theSongIWantToAdd
        --> {user playlist id 20895 of source id 66 of application "iTunes",¬
        --> user playlist id 22255 of source id 66 of application "iTunes"}

    -- Now check if thePlaylistThatNeedsMoreSongs is in that list:
    id of thePlaylistThatNeedsMoreSongs is in id of playlists of theSongIWantToAdd

    if the result is true then
        "Pick another track"
    else
        add theSongIWantToAdd to thePlaylistThatNeedsMoreSongs
    end if
```

Is that sort of what you wanted ?